# How to build and link external CMake dependencies with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, restbed

I'd like to use the following third party library:
https://github.com/Corvusoft/restbed

I'd like to create a folder structure similar to this:

```
- root
     - CMakeLists.txt
     - src
     - third_party
         - restbed
             - src
             - CMakeLists.txt
         - CMakeLists.txt
```

I've found out that I should use the `ExternalProject` CMake module to achieve this but it does not seem that I can do it correctly. For some reason the external lib's (restbed's) source does not appear in my XCode project when I generate it out with the use of the root CMakeLists.txt. This root CMakeLists.txt includes in the `third_party` folder's CMakeLists.txt. The `third_party` folder's CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)

# CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR -> third_party folder
set(RESTBED_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/restbed)

ExternalProject_Add(restbed
    PREFIX ${RESTBED_DIR}
    SOURCE_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_SSL=NO
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND cmake ..
    BINARY_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/build
    INSTALL_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/distribution
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)

set(RESTBED_INCLUDE_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/distribution/include)
set(RESTBED_LIB_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/distribution/lib)

add_library(librestbed IMPORTED STATIC)
add_dependencies(librestbed restbed)
```

After this I'd like to use `target_include_dir` and `target_link_libraries` to add `librestbed` as a dependency to my root project. After this when I build my XCode project nothing happens, the external lib won't get built. What am I doing wrong? I would not like to use the built-in CMake git functionality because I'd like to store my external dependencies as git submodules in the third_party lib. I'd rather not let CMake figure out if it needs to re-download a given dependency. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the cmake command you need is 'add_subdirectory'

Comment: that is different I think because it adds it as a part of my project and not an external one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mixed up the `BUILD_COMMAND` option with the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` option. The `cmake ..` should be placed after the option `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`.

```
ExternalProject_Add(restbed
    PREFIX ${RESTBED_DIR}
    SOURCE_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}
    CMAKE_ARGS -DBUILD_SSL=NO
    DOWNLOAD_COMMAND ""
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND cmake ..
    BINARY_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/build
    INSTALL_DIR ${RESTBED_DIR}/distribution
    INSTALL_COMMAND make install
)
```

Per the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html), there are defaults to each of these commands, so you likely don't have to specify the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND` at all. For example, for `BUILD_COMMAND`:

> If this option is not given, the default build command will be chosen to integrate with the main build in the most appropriate way (e.g. using recursive `make` for Makefile generators or `cmake --build` if the project uses a CMake build).

Also, if you do specify the `CONFIGURE_COMMAND`, you likely expand the arguments you pass it to something like this:

```
    ...
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND cd restbed && mkdir build && cd build && cmake ..
    ...
```